# Android PDF reader with intent extras for page number

Tags: android, pdf

Is anyone aware of a PDF viewer for android that provides intents that allow opening a pdf file to a specific page?

I know I can write my own viewer based on AndroidPdfViewer, MuPDF, pdfjs or others (I have done working samples with all of these), but there are so many already excellent PDF viewers (by Google, Adobe, Moon+, EzPDF, Xodo, etc) which all have great extra features and it would save me a lot of time if I can just put an extra as a page number to the view intent... just not sure if any support this.

Thanks so much!